# callback hell in loop of queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm trying to get a list of distinct values and count of items. like this:

```
sheet_kinds: [
    "cars"      (10 items),
    "computers" (23 items),
    "utilities" (88 items)
],
```

so the query to get distinct values is ok. my code:

```
getValues:function(next){
    Sheet.find().distinct('kind', function(err, rs){
        for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
            Sheet.count({kind:rs[i]}, function(err, c){
                next(null, rs);    <====== THIS IS NOT GOOD
            });
        };
    });
}
```

I cannot run next() inside a loop, I know. But how can I get a full list of count values and run next() only after all items back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of scenario you'd be much better off using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Install

```
npm install --save async
```

Require

```
var async = require('async');
```

Use

```
getValues:function(next){
    Sheet.find().distinct('kind', function(err, rs){
        async.map(rs, function (item, done) {
            Sheet.count({kind:item}, done);
        }, next);
    });
}
```

Details

```
getValues:function(next){

    Sheet.find().distinct('kind', function(err, rs){

        // async.map is used to map a collection asynchronously
        // the cb will be invoked once for each item in rs
        async.map(rs, function (item, done) {

            // the done callback needs to be invoked exactly once
            // in this case, we just pass it to count, since
            // the (err, count) result is exactly what we want (getting us the count)
            Sheet.count({kind:item}, done);

        // next is invoked with the err, if any, and
        // the resulting map (an array of counts)
        }, next);

    });
}
```

#### Update

Addresses question in comments

```
getValues:function(next){
    Sheet.find().distinct('kind', function(err, rs){
        async.map(rs, function (item, done) {
            Sheet.count({kind:item}, function (err, count) {
                done(err, {kind:item,count:count});
            });
        }, next);
    });
}
```

Comment: amazing, this works. I was using async library in other case. thanks!

Comment: one question: where is the done callback defined? this is resulting in an array with count of items and I'm trying to get an associative array of kinds and counts

Comment: the done cb is basically taking what `.count` returns. if that's not what you want, then you need to wrap it, see my updated answer.